# My code does not print the variable called coins

Tags: c, cs50

How come my code is not printing the `int` called `coins`?
I do not see any error while running the debugging system.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{  // getting the user validation  
    printf("please enter a amount of change \n");

    int change = get_int();
    int coins = 0;
    if (change > 0 && change <= 0  && change != 0)
        printf("Change: %i\n", change);

    if (change > 0)
    {
        printf("Change: %i\n", change);
    }

    if (change < 0 )
    {
        printf("please enter a positve number \n");
    }

    if (change == 0)
    {
        printf("Coins: 0 \n");
    }
    //were it counts the amount of coins


    float changef = (int)change;
    float qaurter = 0.25;
    float dime = 0.10;
    float nickel = 0.05;
    float penny = 0.01;



    while (changef / qaurter)
    {
     coins++;
     return changef - qaurter;
    }

    while (changef / dime)
    {
     coins++;
     return changef - dime;
    }

    while (changef / nickel)
    {
     coins++;
     return changef - nickel;
    }

    while (changef / penny)
    {
     coins++;
     return changef - penny;
    }
    printf("Coins: %i\n",coins);

}
```

Comment: In `if (change > 0 && change <= 0  && change != 0)` the first two conditions cannot *both* be true.

Comment: Please learn to format your code, and post it formatted. It's annoying reading unformatted code. Use `%` which is the module operator. Beside, what do you mean by "is not printing?" When dealing with currency you also should not use `float` and `doubles`, that will lead to wrong results on the long term

Comment: Please read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) There are *many many* "change" questions here. It is rarely satisfactory to use floating point types.

Comment: `float changef = (int)change;` does not make sense. Don#t use casts unless you 1) really have to **and** 2) **fully** understand what they do and why you have to use them. And never use floating point if you need exact results, e.g. when dealing with currencies.

Comment: Your loops have `return` statements in them.  Returning from `main()` is equivalent to exiting the program.  You need to revise the code to avoid using `return` in the loops.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't read that far: it seems to be the answer to the title statement since `printf("Coins: %i\n",coins);` is never reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loops are written with `return` statements in them:

```
while (changef / qaurter)
{
    coins++;
    return changef - qaurter;
}
```

Returning from `main()` is equivalent to exiting the program.  You need to revise the code to avoid using `return` in the loops.  For example (including a spelling fix):

```
while (changef / quarter)
{
    coins++;
    changef -= quarter;
}
```

Though frankly, you could avoid loops altogether:

```
int extra = changef / quarter;
coins += extra;
changef -= extra * quarter;
```

However, there's more surgery to do before that's feasible since you only make change for integer numbers of dollars, but your have `quarter` and friends defined as `float` variables with fractional values.  You either need to work in cents only (`int quarter = 25;`), or allow the user to enter a floating point value in the first place, or …

Comment: As we know, reading a floating point value and using floating point arithmetics for this simple application is calling for more problems, because of floating point precision issues. But it is a very tool to teach a few basic concepts and pitfalls.